# How to link together a Windows Phone Store App with a Windows Desktop Store App?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-store

We have two Apps with the same functionality, one in the Windows Desktop Store and one in the Windows Phone Store.

The names of the Apps are slightly different.
The desktop version of the app is targeting Windows 8.
The phone version is targeting Windows Phone 8.

Now we would like to release a Universal App for Windows 10. For this we need to link/merge them to one App in the dev center dashboard.

How to do this?

Comment: If I remember right you can link the store app to the phone app when you create an update for the phone app

Answer (score 1):

the link between you mobile app and your desktop app should have been done before your developer account was migrated to the unified windows store that occured last summer (June 2015 to August 2015) as detailed [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/05/01/get-ready-for-the-unified-dev-center-dashboard-preview-and-upcoming-store-changes/). Now it's too late : the only solution for you is to submit a new app, reserve a unique name for it and upload the universal package (appxbundle). You'll then have to manage 3 versions separately on the store (WP8, W8 and W10).